# Sum of sin() results in asm(x87)

Tags: assembly, x87

I need to calculate the sum of `y(i) = sin(5*i)` in degree, where `i` is increased every iteration. I need to calculate the sum before it becomes greater than 3, and find `i` when the sum is greater.

With the code below, I get an infinite loop:

```
int main() {

float Sum=0;
long i=0;
long A=5;
long B=180;
int C=3;

 _asm{
   finit
 m1:
   inc i
   fldpi    ; load PI
   fmul i   ; PI * i 
   fmul A   ; PI * i * 5
   fdiv B   ; PI * i * 5 / 180 (value in degree)
   fsin ; sin(PI * i * 5 / 180)
   fadd Sum ; counter all lopps result
   ficom C  ; check if lower than 3 go to m1 
   jg m1
 }  
}
```

Comment: i have infinity loop and Sum all time =0.0000 i see it in debuger

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few problems there.

1. `FMUL` expects floating point arguments, but you pass `long`.
2. `FICOM` only sets FPU flags, you have to move them to CPU or use `FCOMI`.
3. `JG` is checking wrong flags, you need to check the carry flag.
4. Your code unbalances the floating point stack.

Bonus: Since 5*PI/180 is constant, you can precalculate that.

You could use some code like this (adjust for your compiler's syntax, this is for gnu assembler):

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.globl main
main:
    sub esp, 16               # allocate space for i, sum and fmt
    mov dword ptr [esp+4], -1 # i
    fild dword ptr [limit]    # limit
    fldz                      # sum
1:
    inc dword ptr [esp+4]     # i += 1
    fild dword ptr [esp+4]    # i
    fmul qword ptr [factor]   # i * factor
    fsin
    faddp                     # add to sum
    fcomi st, st(1)           # check if below limit
    jb 1b
    fstp qword ptr [esp+8]    # store on stack for printf
    fstp st(0)                # remove limit from fpu stack
    mov dword ptr [esp], offset fmt
    call printf
    add esp, 16               # clean up stack
    xor eax, eax              # return value
    ret

.data
factor: .double .08726646259971647884 # 5 * PI / 180
limit: .int 3
fmt: .string "i=%d sum=%g\n"
```

[See in operation.](http://ideone.com/dctMdn)

Comment: try to set lll var like float but it didn't help. The sun not increased

Comment: i do that but loop stil not work correct

    int main() {

 float Sum=0;
 int i=0;
 int A=5;
 int B=180;
 int C=3;
 
    _asm{
       finit
    m1:inc i
       fldpi
       fimul A 
       fimul i
       fidiv B
       fsin
       fadd Sum 
       fstp Sum
       fild Sum
       ficom C  
       fstsw AX  
       sahf   
      jc m1
    }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's offtopic, but using simple trigonometric identities, you can calculate answer without any loops for arbitrary sum value with a simple formula:

```
i=ceil(acos(cos(t/2)-2*result_sum*sin(t/2))/t-0.5)
```

where t is your step angle (5 degrees), result_sum - needed acumulated sum of consecutive sines (=3 in your case)