# Why loop failed in asm(x87)

Tags: assembly, x87

I have some calculation in asm in loop, it must be before Sum will be 3, but loop work all time and never ending. Here is mu code:

```
int main() {

    float Sum=0;
    int i=0;
    int A=5;
    int B=180;
    int C=3;

_asm{
   finit
m1:inc i
   fldpi
   fimul A  
   fimul i
   fidiv B
   fsin
   fadd Sum 
   fstp Sum
   fild Sum
   ficom C      
   fstsw AX     
   sahf         
   jg   m1
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sum of sin() results in asm(x87)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212795/sum-of-sin-results-in-asmx87)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FPU's condition flags have completely different meanings than the condition flags in the EFLAGS register.

If `Sum` is greater than `C`, then the `ficom` will set the FPU condition flags to "C3=0, C2=0, C1=0". When loaded into the CPU's EFLAGS register (via. `fstsw` and `sahf`) this becomes "ZF=0, PF=0, CF=0". The `jg` instruction will branch if "ZF=0" and "SF=0" - it won't test the PF flag or the CF flag at all, but will test the irrelevant SF flag.

Given that you're comparing integers anyway; you should probably just do:

```
mov eax,[Sum]
cmp [C],eax
jg m1
```

The alternative is to test the flags in AX directly. For example:

```
ficom C
fstsw AX
test AX,0x4500    ;Are C3, C2 and C0 clear?
je m1             ; yes, Sum must be greater than C
```

Comment: in second code same infinity loop, it is not stops when sum more than 3